No such file or directory - installing the jekyll gem
To implement a localhost server, I've installed Ruby and now i need to run the following commands in the CMD:
gem install jekyll
gem install bundler

Afterward, i go to the directory:
C:\projects\HABU289-github-blog\HABU289.github.io
and execute:
bundle install
PS C:\projects\HABU289-github-blog> cd HABU289.github.io
PS C:\projects\HABU289-github-blog\HABU289.github.io> bundle install

[!] There was an error while loading minimal-mistakes-jekyll.gemspec: No such file or directory - git ls-files -z. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from C:/projects/HABU289-github-blog/HABU289.github.io/minimal-mistakes-jekyll.gemspec:16
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    spec.add_development_dependency "rake", ">= 12.3.3"
 >  end
 #  require "json"
 #  -------------------------------------------
PS C:\projects\HABU289-github-blog\HABU289.github.io>

However, the command results in this error. How can I resolve this issue ?

Do you have git installed? It seems like it failed trying to run the git command.
